# How to add Export methods to an existing tree structure while conforming to "good" OOP practices?

Tags: design-patterns

We have a tree structure that consists of different types of nodes, and I am given the task of writing some code that exports the tree to some XML format.

Each node inherits from some base node, and so they can inherit the base export method, but for a couple types of nodes I need to write a custom export method since their data is stored in an "interesting" way.

The nodes currently only contain data and a couple methods related to tree management. I feel that it is better design to avoid adding export methods to the nodes themselves, cause that means a node is handling multiple responsibilities (managing its parent/children, exporting)

The export process would basically start with the root node and recursively call `export`, so ideally I could just implement an `export` method

I am looking for a way (like maybe a design pattern) that will allow me to write all of the export code in a separate class, while taking advantage of the fact that the nodes have some inheritance hierarchy.

This will be written in java if it makes a difference.

Comment: Sounds like Visitor design pattern can be used to traverse the tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have two options,

- Implement a `Export` virtual method on the base class, which can be overriden on derived classes as needed, or
- Use a Visitor pattern, as suggested in the comments.

From my point of view, implementing a virtual method on the base class is probably the fastest approach, without the implication of major design flaws. However, on the long run, the implementation for the `Export` method might change dramatically: say you need to export nodes as JSON objects, or that given a set of conditions the exports need to be both XML and JSON, or simply a POCO, or print them to a FileStream.

At this point the advantages of having the exporting code reside outside the class itself are more apparent as the `Export` method can grow really quickly to handle these multiple scenarios. The node class can remain agnostic as to what the visitor is (could be a `XmlVisitor` or `JsonVisitor`) and what it does, so adding or modifying the exporting procedures implies no change to the domain objects at all. They simply need to take an `IVisitor` object that knows how to process them.

Comment: I wrote an exporter interface that was implemented by an XML exporter. It was easy to write a different exporter by implementing the interface, and didn't require any changes to the nodes that were already set up to accept the interface. Works nicely and much more flexible than having a virtual method and having all the nodes implement the export logic themselves.